# How to pass AB testing parameters in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to do AB testing and then compare the data between them. 
I am going to run two separate tests for this. But I am not sure how to pass the AB parameters. Right now I am passing the site url and then calling the api in HTTP Request. I need to send ?site=test-a0 in the end of the url and then call the api. 
example. let's say the url I used to test is www.google.com. Now I need to use www.google.com/?site=test-a0
I am not sure how to do it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) to apply the parameter to all [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in scope

[image: HTTP Request Defaults]

You can also use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as a parameter value like: `${__P(site,)}` so you will be able to pass the property value via command-line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Jsite=test-a0 -n -t ....
```

Comment: I tried by adding parameters in HTTP Request Defaults, but I am not sure if it is working as i expected. Without the AB parameter the url with api call would be www.google.com/api/...............Now after passing the parameters, it is www.google.com/api/.........&site=test-a0. It looks like it is retrieving the same kind of results in both test-a0 and test-b0. so I am wondering if it is really getting results from A and B

Comment: and when I test the site manually I would use the url www.google.com/?site=test-a0

Comment: I added it in the HTTP Request parameters and it is working now. Thank you!